# File upload with nextJS and Laravel - $request->hasFile() return false

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, upload, multipartform-data

i'm trying to make a file upload with Laravel API and Next.JS front-end, but i don't know why, laravel returnl false everytime i try to call the API with Axios as POST Method.

Here is my front-end code :

```js
const updateCompanyLogo = (e) => {
        setLogo(e.target.files[0])
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("logo", logo);
        axios.post('api/company/logo',
            { formData },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }
        ).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        console.log("Change detected")
    }

    <input className=" mt-5 form-control block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal  text-gray-700  bg-gray-200 bg-clip-padding rounded transition ease-in-out h-10 m-0 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-white" type="file" id="logo" onChange={updateCompanyLogo} />
```

```php
public function update_logo(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            return 'found';
        } else {
            return 'not found';
        }
    }
```

"not found" is the respond i get evrytime.

Thank's for help.

Comment: Do you have  `encType="multipart/form-data" ` attribute in your form?

Comment: I don't need to pass a form, i want to send it on Enchange.
I don't have <form>
I just set the header via axios :
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }

Comment: try  `const formData = { file:  e.target.result };`  insteed  `let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("logo", logo);`  and decode base64 string at laravel side

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the name attribute in your input field.

```
<input name="logo" type="file" id="logo" onChange={updateCompanyLogo} />
```

Comment: I got the event with it : onChange={updateCompanyLogo}